# HTML5 localStorage and Dojo

Tags: html, dojo

I am working in DOJO and my task is i have one JSON file and the datas are coming from JSON url. So now i have to read JSON url and save the datas to browser using HTML5 localStorage, after saving i have to read datas from browser and i have to display in DOJO. Guys any one know about this kindly help me..

Answer (score 1):

**Function for getting json data**

```
function accessDomain(dom_sclapi, handle) {
        var apiResponse;
        //accessSameDomain
        if(!handle) {
            handle = "json";
        }
        dojo.xhrGet({
            url : dom_sclapi,
            handleAs: handle,
            sync: true,
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json" },
            //Success
            load: function(Response) { 
                apiResponse = Response;
            },
            // Ooops!  Error!
            error: function(Error, ioArgs) {
                //apiResponse = Error;
                //console.log(ioArgs.xhr.status);
            }
        });
        //apiResponse
        return apiResponse;
        }
where dom_sclapi = <json url>
```

**Call**

`var data = accessDomain(<jsonurl>,'json');`

**then**

```
console.log(data);
```

You can see the json o/p in console window. Now you can dispaly to html page using,

```
dojo.forEach(data, function(eachData){
  //script for each json element eg: eachData.displayName;                                
});
```